# scaling an object by a factor of exactly ten

Tags: modeling

how do i scale a thing to x 10?

There must be a way to get numeric options for scaling? and here i'm just typing a few things because it wont let me post such a short and precise question as i wrote initially. i hope this has enough words now. no it wasn't what more do i have to do? hello AI why aren't you better than this? I feel super annoyed that an AI prevents me from asking a very simple question can you please stay out of human ways of talking mr AI?

thank you times ten.

Answer (score 1):

you type in x 10 in the scale properties - so if scale is 1.000 you write 1.000 x 10 in the scale properties panel

Answer (score 0):

In object mode we can scale using the toolbar on the upper right.

[image: Scaling an object in object mode]

And in edit mode we can do precise scaling with popup once we scale it. It should appear in the bottom left, and you simply expand it.

[image: Scale options in edit mode]